# Heavy Ion-collision and Big Bang

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, big-bang, heavy-ion

I have read heavy ion-collision can be used as a source of information about early universe but I don't know how these two are related. I would be glad if someone gives me a reference about this topic or just explains it for me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a layman's answer:

It has to do with temperature.  The very early universe is thought to have been incredibly hot, much hotter than the inside of a star, and it cooled rapidly as it expanded rapidly.   For a chronology of temperature to time, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#Very_early_universe) has a pretty good summary.

When 2 particles are smashed together at near light speed, similar temperatures are reached to about 1 second after the big bang, but only for a quick moment in time and only at the collision.   It's perhaps not accurate to say that it creates "conditions" of the early universe, but it replicates temperature of the Early universe, which gives the scientists a a window to study, but it's not a complete recreation, as that would probably be impossible.

[This article](http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/november-2013/the-early-universe) gives a pretty good layman's summary.

[This article](http://www.dailygalaxy.com/my_weblog/2011/06/cern-lhc-creates-temperatures-1000-times-hotter-than-center-of-sun.html) discusses the temperatures reached by collisions at Cern.   About one second after the big bang is as far as we can go right now.